# Renaming Nginx 1.3.5 Server: response header

Tags: webserver, rename, nginx

In nginx 1.2 & 1.3 you can modify the source to change the name:

src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c (lines 48 and 49):

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: Not Nginx" CRLF;
static char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: Not Nginx/1.0" CRLF;
```

Renaming those and recompiling the source changes the server response name in nginx 1.2.

However doing this in 1.3 does not seem to change the name. It still says **nginx/1.3.5** and with server_tokens off; it just says **nginx**.

How can I change the server name in 1.3 without installing the 3rd party addon headers more? I want to compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

Change: `src/http/modules/perl/Makefile.PL`

Where it reads:

```
NAME              => 'nginx',
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with Nginx 1.3.7. You can still use the same technique as before.

Change: `src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c`

Where it reads:

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: nginx" CRLF;
```

and then change: `src/core/nginx.h`

Where it reads:

```
#define NGINX_VERSION      "1.3.7"
#define NGINX_VER          "nginx/" NGINX_VERSION
```